# Including navigation property with select

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
repo
.Where(x=>x.Id==id)
.Include(x=>x.History.Select(c=>c.ProductInfo)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Above query should return all bought products by given user, and must contains Product details.
It works.So there is no problem with navigation properties.

Now I want to split product to `Delivered` and `notDelivered`

```
               repo
               .Where(x => x.Id == id)
               .Include(x=>x.History.Select(c=>c.ProductInfo))
               .Select(x => 
                   new Details { User = x,
                                 notDelivered = x.History.Where(k=>!k.IsDelivered),
                                 Delivered=x.History.Where(k=>k.IsDelivered)})
               .FirstOrDefault();
```

It divide product like it should, but ProductInfo is always null.I have no idea why this doesn't select `ProductInfo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a projection `Include` is ignored. You can try to add a `ProductInfos` property of type `IEnumerable<ProductInfo>` to your `Details` class and fill that collection inside the projection:

```
repo.Where(x => x.Id == id)
    .Select(x => 
        new Details { User = x,
                      notDelivered = x.History.Where(k=>!k.IsDelivered),
                      Delivered = x.History.Where(k=>k.IsDelivered),
                      ProductInfos = x.History.Select(k=>k.ProductInfo) })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Automatic relationship fixup should add the loaded `ProductInfo`s to the loaded `History` entities - as if they had been loaded with `Include`.